# Evolution calendar month view as default

Tags: evolution, calendar

I use Evolution as Email and Calendar client, but when I open the Calendar view, I see the task in list view by default, and then I can change to month view (and other views). I would that the default view for Evolution Calendar become the month view. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

In Evolution **below v3.29.92**, List view is forced with the *Active Appointments* and *Next 7 Days' Appointments* filters. Try with other filters like *Any Category* and it would make the last used view (Month View, Day View etc,.) as default view.

Related issue: [GNOME/evolution#47](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/issues/47)